# How find specific item in object of array by use find in javascrip

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I want to make a function to find specific address as (tokia) after that return name. I tried this code but not give me the name only.

```
 let  info = [
  {name: "ola",  address: "tokia"},
  {name: "omar",  address: "mokla"},
  {name: "ohod",  address: "gola"}
  ]
function  findNam(info)
{ if(info.address==="tokia")
  { return info.name; }   }
 console.log(info.find(findNam))
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: yes but i want  use find inside of function not in console .. i want function to return the name

Comment: See the second part of my answer.

Comment: it works .. thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the name property with dot notation. `find` returns the element that matches the condition, not what you return from the callback.

```
console.log(info.find(findNam).name)
```

You can use destructuring to store the name in a variable.

```
const {name} = info.find(findNam);
console.log(name);
```